# Node.JS API, how to integrate Cache

Tags: node.js

I have the following code that returns data (it requires user detail & a product Id). I want to add caching to prevent a quicker response time. How can I do this. In order to enable caching, should it be a GET request, bearing in mind that I am transmitting tokens to authenticate?

```
ProductRoute.post('/data', userAuth, (req, res) => {

    
    var productId = req.body.productId;

    if (!validate.STRING(productId)) {
        res.apiError(messages.server.invalid_request);
    } else {

        dbProduct.findOne({
          
            productId: productId
        }).then(dbRes => {

            if (dbRes !== null) {
                res.apiSuccess({
                    assetImages: dbRes.assetImages,             
                    productStatus: dbRes.productStatus,
                    createdDate: dbRes.createdDate,
                    title: dbRes.title,
                    details: dbRes.details,
                    features: dbRes.features,
                                                         
                });
            } else {
                res.apiError(messages.product.not_found);
            }

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based/unhelpful to future visitors, but seems like a GET to me. As an aside, I'd use `return res.apiError(messages.server.invalid_request);` so you can remove the `else` blocks and simplify your code a bit.

Comment: it probably does matter, im assuming u have 0 control over ProductRoute

Answer (score 1):

The REST HTTP [guidelines](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) suggests

> GET  to retrieve resource representation/information only

> POST to create new subordinate resources

However , clearly the code snippet is intended to serve a `POST` request . In `ProductRoute.post('/data',..)` the route is supposed to accept `POST` to `/data` endpoint . Moreover  `req.body.productId;` will only retreive productId from the `POST` body . So if you use a `GET` request the code naturally will not work as body is undefined in case of a `GET` request . You can continue using the endpoint with `POST` or modify the code snippet to accept `GET` instead as all read operations should ideally use `GET` .

```
ProductRoute.get('/data', userAuth, (req, res) => {

var productId = req.query.productId;
```

Comment: One more thing: maybe it's also worth to think about `GET /products` and `GET /products/{id}`, where `id` is a path parameter rather than a query parameter.

Comment: If I modify to use GET, will I need to send productId through URL ? Currently, I'm sending productId, userToken, userSecret through the POST body, is it advisable to switch to GET ?

Comment: Assuming you are using userToken and userSecret for Authorization or Authentication purposes , I would recommend to move them to be sent through `HTTP headers` (where they should ideally be) and use `GET` to pass the non-sensetive productId in URL .